# Titanium/Appcelerator: Cannot find Android theme

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I'm building an Android app using Titanium/Appcelerator, and I'm following their [guide on Android themes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes). According to the guide, to use one of the default Android themes you must:

1. Create a theme XML file in **platform/android/res/values/**
2. Insert their demo XML to enable default Android themes
3. Set the theme in the **TiApp.xml** file

I've done this, however I'm getting an error when trying to build:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Light').

I've noticed that the theme XML file that I created in the directory structure noted above has also disappeared. Why is this? And how can I get the themes to work?

Comment: Provide more info like the folder structure you are putting your theme file at. and the name of the theme you are setting in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are putting your theme file in alloy generated folders which are cleaned up on every build.

The correct structure for theme file is this:

Notice the **themes.xml** file located in the ***app - platform - android - res - values*** folder.

[image]

This could a demo content of your **themes.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">#00ff00</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Now you have theme name as **CustomTheme**, so you can set this name in your **tiapp.xml** file like this:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">

        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Comment: Thanks for including a screen-capture of the directory structure — it makes things clearer